# Write a pig sequence of statements to calculate the number of ratings records and the average rating score by gender

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, average, apache-pig

this is what i have done so far.

```
A = LOAD '.mike/users.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (userID: int, age: int, gender: chararray, occupation: chararray, zip: int);
B = LOAD '.mike/data.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (userID: int, itemid: chararray, rating: int, timestamp: int);
joinAB = JOIN A by userID, B by userID;
describe joinAB;
C = group joinAB by gender;
D = foreach C GENERATE group, AVG(joinAB.rating);
dump D;
```

The error i am getting:

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "hdfs://localhost:9000/mike/users.txt"
Failed to read data from "hdfs://localhost:9000/mike/movies/data.txt"

localhost:9000 show me this:
It looks like you are making an HTTP request to a Hadoop IPC port. This is not the correct port for the web interface on this daemon.

Answer (score 0):

`localhost:9000` is not a web address that you can load in your browser. There is a separate address for WebHDFS, if you have enabled it.

If you want to read data from HDFS, make sure you've used `hdfs dfs -put` command first to upload. Then you should use full paths like `LOAD '/user/mike/users.txt'` (Note: You are missing the `/user/` directory in the error)